# Need to read in a file of any size

Tags: python

I am creating a for loop in Python, which allows me to go through each record of a file to see whether the line is a duplicate or not. I have created a range, which reads through each line in the specified range. I was thinking of putting a range of infinity so taht literally any file size could be read in. But I do not know how to write that or if that is even possible. Below is what I currently have:

for i in range (0,10000):

Comment: Just loop over the file instead? Why do you think you need to hardcode a number of iterations?

Comment: Hi Martijn, but how would you write this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just open the file and it will return you an array of strings per line:

```
with open(file_name) as file:
    line = file.readlines()
```